# Playing a video to start the application xcode

Tags: xcode, ios5, media-player, mpmovieplayercontroller

Playing a video to start the application

I have this code, I can't see the video and I can hear the audio.

Could anyone explain why ?

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{

    NSURL *url2 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tecnolitevideo_1" ofType:@"mov"]];

    moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
                    initWithContentURL:url2];
    [moviePlayer presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];
    [moviePlayer.moviePlayer play];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerPlaybackStateChanged:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];

}


-(void)moviePlayerPlaybackStateChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {

    NSURL* url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"3" withExtension:@"mov"];

            m_player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
            [m_player.backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
            [m_player.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
            [m_player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
            [[m_player view] setFrame:[self.view bounds]];



            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];

            [m_player play];

            [self.view addSubview:[m_player view]];


}

- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)_notification
{




    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:nil];



      [m_player.view removeFromSuperview];
      [m_player stop];

    m_player = nil;
}
```

I am try this and works fine!!!